# My question says it was edited an hour ago by someone else but they didn't change anything?

Tags: discussion, editing

Maybe it doesn't matter, but it seems odd that someone could edit my post and get some modicum of credit for doing so when they literally changed nothing. This person has something like 20k rep so it's kind of weird. Is there anyway for me to roll back the edit the way I do on other stack exchange sites?

Comment: Yeah, it's odd. It says that [21 characters were added to the body](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/45037/revisions), and if you look at the source of the "update", it has a bunch of non-visible extra bytes... Not sure why he did it, but yes, you can roll back the edit on that page I linked, via the rollback link on your last edit (revision 2).

Comment: Thanks @Alconja.  that's what i needed.

Comment: That is definitely weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the user in question, I can tell you the exact sequence of events:

- I went to the review queues and found [this suggested edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25410) to your question.
- After thinking about it for a while, I decided to reject the edit as "no improvement whatsoever". However, I also thought that your post should be edited anyway to add the [game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) tag, since it's about a game. So I hit the "Reject and Edit" button, in order to reject the suggested edit and make one of my own instead.
- But when adding the [game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game) tag, I noticed its tag wiki excerpt: "*A puzzle that asks for determining the winner in a multi-player game.*" That doesn't apply to your question, so I took the tag out again. This meant I had no changes or improvements to make to your post, but I couldn't see a "cancel editing" button, so I had to click "save edits" even though there were no changes to be saved.

So that's why it looks like I edited your question even though I didn't actually make any changes to it. My mistake. Sorry about that.

> Maybe it doesn't matter, but it seems odd that someone could edit my post and get some modicum of credit for doing so when they literally changed nothing.

I'm not sure what you mean by "credit". I don't get any sort of credit for making edits - I've already got all the badges it's possible to get from editing posts, so at this point my only reason for making edits is what the reason should always be: to improve the site.

> This person has something like 20k rep so it's kind of weird.

Not sure what my rep has to do with anything. (And that's 38k, thank you very much! :-P )

> Is there anyway for me to roll back the edit the way I do on other stack exchange sites?

Yep, and it looks like [you've already done so](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/45037/revisions).

Comment: Knew there'd be some amusingly convoluted, but ultimately boring reason. Why can't there ever be a *real* conspiracy? Also, re: credit, I think he means "apparent authorship", not "reward". A post displays the last editor's name/profile just as prominently as the actual creator creating the impression that they may have had more input in the puzzle than they did...

Comment: This was an enjoyable read! Thanks :) much more boring than my preferred story of someone writing a bot that mines the site for easy rep and badges. (I would have simply asked you were there a way to messages users directly).